# XMLHttpRequest is returning nothing?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a small JavaScript program that makes web calls to pull up weather information for when the user clicks on a map. This is my code:

```
    //get the three letter airport code
    var text = kmlEvent.featureData.name;

    //service to get woeid
    var woeid_url = 'http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?name=';
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //has to be sync, since next request depends on it
    xmlhttp.open('POST', woeid_url + text, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    //now we get the relevent info from the XML
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    woeid_xml = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('woeid');
    //parse the xml and get the woeid
    woeid = woeid_xml[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    //with the woeid found, we can make the weather request
    weatherhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var weather_url = 'http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=' + woeid + '&u=f';
    //this is async
    weatherhttp.open('POST', weather_url, true);
    weatherhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (weatherhttp.readyState == 4) {
        alert(weatherhttp.status);
        }
    }
    weatherhttp.send(null);
```

It makes calls to Yahoo to get the woeid for the location the user clicks. This works and I get the woeid just fine. However, when I make the second call the weather service, it returns nothing and 0 as the status code.

If I change the second part to be sync instead of async, I still get the same error. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? If I copy the weather_url into my browser, loads it just fine. I don't understand why the first part works, but not the second. I'm very new to JavaScript and AJAX, so I really have no idea what I am doing.

The browser I am using is FireFox, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest using a framework such as Prototype or JQuery since you said you're new to JS, especially when it comes to AJAX. They both big-time iron out and simplify things for you.

My guess to your lack of data is that you're request is trying to load data from a different domain - See [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Test out loading something within your domain to see if this is indeed the issue.

Stay away from synchronous AJAX calls! Ideally, you'd do the things that depend on the response of the first request once you receive the data, usually in a callback. Again, this is something that frameworks will let you easily accomplish: [Check out the 'onSuccess' here](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Request/)

Comment: My first call to 'where.yahooapis.com' is on a different domain, though, and that works. But then 'weather.yahooapis.com' does not. Would the Same Origin Policy cause this behavior?

Comment: You can get around the Same Origin Policy completely by building a proxy, i.e., create a page that handles the requests and forwards them to yahoo.  Such as `myserver.com/where.php?name=blah` makes a server-side request for `http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?name=blah` and returns the result to the caller.

Comment: I just tried your code in jsfiddle and got this error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12519826&u=f. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` It appears to be an SOP issue. Can you see any errors being thrown in firebug?

Comment: It seems the where.yahooapis.com is setup to allow this type of cross-domain scripting. The response header includes `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, which is why that one does not error out. weather.yahooapis.com does not appear to be similarly setup, so access is denied ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control for more info). As @mellamokb said, there are ways around the SOP (which you can look into), but this is the answer to your current question.

Comment: That makes sense, then. I'll have to go around the policy somehow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `GET` instead of `POST` as your method.  Per [the documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/guide/requests.html):

> The PlaceFinder Web service supports only the HTTP GET method. Other HTTP methods are not supported.

You can also compare the calls using a proxy sniffer like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see if there are differences between the successful call manually made in the browser versus the one generated via AJAX.